# Trying to remove symbol (" - ") with whitespace while keeping symbol ("-") without whitespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, whitespace, symbols, alphabetical-sort

I have a txt file I open in Python. And I'm trying to remove the symbols and order the remaining words alphabetically. Removing the periods, the commas etc. isn't a problem. However, I can't seem to remove the dash symbol with whitespaces when I add it to a list together with the rest of the symbols.

This is an example of what I open:

`content = "The quick brown fox - who was hungry - jumps over the 7-year old lazy dog."`

This is what I want (periods removed, and dash symbols which aren't attached to a word removed):

`content = "The quick brown fox who was hungry jumps over the 7-year old lazy dog"`

But I either get this (all dash symbols removed):

`content = "The quick brown fox who was hungry jumps over the 7year old lazy dog"`

Or this (dash symbol unremoved):

`content = "The quick brown fox - who was hungry - jumps over the 7-year old lazy dog"`

This is my entire code. Adding a content.replace() works. But that isn't what I want:

```
f = open("article.txt", "r")

# Create variable (Like this removing " - " works)
content = f.read()
content = content.replace(" - ", " ")

# Create list
wordlist = content.split()

# Which symbols (If I remove the line "content = content.replace(" - ", " ")", the " - " in this list doesn't get removed here)
chars = [",", ".", "'", "(", ")", "‘", "’", " - "]

# Remove symbols
words = []
for element in wordlist:
    temp = ""
    for ch in element:
        if ch not in chars:
            temp += ch
    words.append(temp)

# Print words, sort alphabetically and do not print duplicates
for word in sorted(set(words)):
    print(word)
```

It works like this. But when I remove the `content = content.replace(" - ", " ")`, the "whitespace + dash symbol + whitspace" in `chars` doesn't get removed.

And if I replace it with "-" (no whitespaces), I get this which I don't want:

`content = "The quick brown fox who was hungry jumps over the 7year old lazy dog"`

Is it possible at all to do this with a list like `chars` or is my only option to do this with a .replace().

And is there a particular reason why Python orders capitalized words alphabetically first, and uncapitalized words later separately?

Like this (The letters ABC are just added to emphasize what I'm trying to say):

```
7-year
A
B
C
The
brown
dog
fox
hungry
jumps
lazy
old
over
quick
the
was
who
```

Comment: That's an easy task for `re.sub()`. Check my answer. :-)

Comment: The capital letters are ordered first because their `ASCII` code are lower than the ones from their lower case counterparts. You can easily check that with `ord('A')` and `ord('a')`. If you want to sort the words ignoring their case you can do `sorted(your_word_list, key=lambda x: x.lower())`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` like this:

```py
>>> import re
>>> strip_chars = re.compile('(?:[,.\'()‘’])|(?:[-,]\s)')
>>> content = "The quick brown fox - who was hungry - jumps over the 7-year old lazy dog."
>>> strip_chars.sub("", content)
'The quick brown fox who was hungry jumps over the 7-year old lazy dog'
>>> strip_chars.sub("", content).split()
['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'who', 'was', 'hungry', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', '7-year', 'old', 'lazy', 'dog']
>>> print(*sorted(strip_chars.sub("", content).split()), sep='\n')
7-year
The
brown
dog
fox
hungry
jumps
lazy
old
over
quick
the
was
who
```

Summarizing my comments and putting it all together:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter
import re

strip_chars = re.compile('(?:[,.\'()‘’])|(?:[-,]\s)')

article = Path('/path/to/your/article.txt')

content = article.read_text()

words = Counter(strip_chars.sub('', content).split())

for word in sorted(words, key=lambda x: x.lower()):
    print(word)
```

If `The` and `the`, for example, count as duplicate words then you just need to convert `content` to lower case letters. The code would be this one instead:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter
import re

strip_chars = re.compile('(?:[,.\'()‘’])|(?:[-,]\s)')

article = Path('/path/to/your/article.txt')

content = article.read_text().lower()

words = Counter(strip_chars.sub('', content).split())

for word in sorted(words):
    print(word)
```

Finally, as a good side effect of using `collections.Counter`, you also get a words counter in `words` and you can answer questions like "what are the top ten most common words?" with something like:

```py
words.most_common(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This works. But how should I remove the duplicate words in this situation?

Comment: If the text is really long, I would go with `collections.Counter` (because I'm lazy and don't want to reinvent the wheel :-) like this: `sorted(Counter(strip_chars.sub("", content).split()).keys())`.

Comment: `The` and `the` counts as duplicate words? If that's the case, then you just need to work with `content.lower()`.

Comment: Yes, `The` and `the` are in this situation duplicates. But that isn't a priority right now. I was trying to figure out a way to expand a preexisting txt file with new words. But I hadn't figured out yet how to do that with words that are both used capitalized and uncapitalized or words existing out of multiple words (for example "The New York Times"). I'm not sure whether I should bother to keep such words together or I should separate them into multiple words.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
wordlist = content.split()
```

your list no longer contains anything with starting/ending whitespaces.

```
str.split()
```

removes consecutive whitespaces. So there is no `' - '` in your split list.

Doku: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

> - str.**split**(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
>
> If `sep` is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of *consecutive whitespace* are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain *no empty strings* at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

---

Replacing `' - '` seems right - the other way to keep close to your code would be to remove exactly `'-'` from your split list:

```
content = "The quick brown fox - who was hungry - jumps over the 7-year old lazy dog."
wordlist = content.split()

print(wordlist)

chars = [",", ".", "'", "(", ")", "‘", "’"]   # modified

words = []
for element in wordlist:
    temp = ""
    if element == '-':             # skip pure -
        continue
    for ch in element:             # handle characters to be removed
        if ch not in chars:
            temp += ch
    words.append(temp)
```

Output:

```
['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', '-', 'who', 'was', 'hungry', '-', 
 'jumps', 'over', 'the', '7-year', 'old', 'lazy', 'dog.']

7-year
The
brown
dog
fox
hungry
jumps
lazy
old
over
quick
the
was
who
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, what should I use a a separator? Or would I be unnecessarily overcomplicating the situation.

Comment: @johnny you either stick with your `t = t.replace(' - ',' ')` or handle `'-'` in your split list differently from other chars to replace - because you want only to remove splits that are equal to `'-'` - not all `'-'` characters anywhere in your splitted words. Your code is slow because it "adds" strings together - which will create/dispose lots of intermediate strings because strings are immuteable in python so if you do `c = 'abc' + 'd'` it will create a string `'abc'` and a string `'d'` and create a string `'abcd'` and restroy `'abc'` and `'d'` again. Regular expressions would be better ...

Comment: @johnny to deal with your task. As a rule of thumb- dont add strings, use lists of characters instead and `final_String = str.join("",yourlist)` them at the end. Lists are desinged to be added to and make it faster. RegEx are designed to to regular matching and replacing, so that would be best here (imho).